# Android integer within listpreference

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have a preference xml file and a listpreference.

The listpreference entryValues and entries are in a array.xml file.

Here's the problem, the entries/entryValues contain "10 mb/s" and i would like to get the int value from that entry/whatever is selected.

This gives me an error however, here is the code:

```
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String result = sp.getString("BITRATE", "8");

    int i = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(" mb/s")));

    t.setText("Int value: " + i);
```

As i said this gives me an error and i cannot find the issue.

Thanks for any help!

*FINAL FIXED CODE*

```
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String result = sp.getString("BITRATE", "3");

    int intRes = Integer.parseInt(result);

    t.setText("Int value: " + intRes);
```

Also i changed the preferences entryValues items to only be integers instead of ex 10mb/s to just 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `entryValues` array containing only the integers. The `entries` are used when displaying to the user, the entryValues are what is stored in your preferences (and are not displayed). The two arrays do not have to have the same contents, but they should have the same number of items.

```
<string-array name="bitrate_entries">
    <item>10 mb/s</item>
    <item>25 mb/s</item>
    <item>50 mb/s</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="bitrate_entry_values">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>50</item>
</string-array>
```

Now you only need to use `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Hmm well no errors although it doesen't return my preferences listpreference value, it returns the default value when i call sp.getInt, which is 3 however in my ListPReference default value it is 8.

Comment: @YOYOYO make sure you are using the correct shared preferences key. You can also specify a `android:defaultValue` in your preferences xml.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it! Thanks a bunch really helped me :)

Comment: @YOYOYO You should ask a new question. it's not clear what you are trying to do.